# reinforcement learning when there are more than one decision to learn

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is there any work on how to learn more than one decision in reinforcement learning? For instance, a firm may want to know how to set optimal price and how to replenish products from suppliers at the same time. In that case, the agent in the RL needs to learn both policies at the same time. Any algorithm could achieve this goal?

I tried searching for multiple policy, multiple agents, and multiple objects. But I am not sure whether they are the right way to solve the issue.

Comment: I think you should think about the reward design. I suggest you to think about your constrains and design a function that can compose both of your decision

Comment: @DanielChepenko I think I have an idea of the reward structure. Suppose we have a firm hoping to know optimal pricing, replenishment policy and product assignment. The actions will affect both current reward the state transition, and the behavior of customers in the future.

Comment: But why do you want to store it one model?

Comment: @DanielChepenko cuz those policies, eg pricing, replenishment, ect. might be related to each other. For instance, the price affects how fast products will be sold, which in turn affects when shall I re-order. Do you have any suggestion how I could formulate the problem?

Comment: @TracyYang, maybe Multiobjective Reinforcement Learning could be interesting for you. I think the general approach is closer to learn a unique policy that trade-off different objectives, instead of having different policies, as you suggest. Good luck!

Comment: @PabloEM can multiobjective RL apply to the case where I want to learn two actions (or policies), one action for one objective and the other action for the other objective?